# Can't click toolbar or dock

Tags: mouse, dock

The dock and toolbar sometimes become unresponsive to mouse events after logging out and back in between different user accounts on my Ubuntu 15.10 laptop computer. Even hovering over the top bar when a window is full-screen doesn't reveal window controls or menus. The keyboard can still trigger menu navigation using the alt key, and after a menu is activated using the keyboard, the menu items respond to mouse clicks and hover and can even activate other menus, but the top bar still doesn't respond to mouse clicks, even on menu headers and even when menus are activated.

Is there a way other than rebooting to recover from this problem?